# Is there a way to organise my Pyomo code into submodels that are loaded together into the solver?

Tags: python, optimization, model, pyomo, ampl

I have some experience with AMPL before modelling some complex systems. I was able to divide up my model into smaller submodels and load the together in a "model.run" file.

My question is if anyone knows if it is possible to have the same structure with pyomo? The purpose is to have a clean and easy to read and edit code.

In AMPL I was able to organize my code like this:

```
model mainmodel.mod
data mainmodel.dat

model submodel1.mod
data submodel1.dat

model submodel2.mod
data submodel2.dat

model submodel3.mod
data submodel3.dat
```

Thanks for any help, I have tried searching for an answer, but it doesn't seem to be any mentioning of this way of organising the code.

Best Regards,
Alex